# Delete factory mode chinese tablet MTK

Tags: android, preloader

I have a colorfly g808 and i would like to delete the factory mode on the tablet.
Now i think the factory mode is build in the preloader.
Source: https://sturmflut.github.io/mediatek/2015/07/04/mediatek-details-partitions-and-preloader/

When i press home and vol - when the tablet boots it goes to factory mode.

What i am looking for, is some way to delete the connection between the buttons and factory mode.
Or.., delete the whole factory mode itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed the rom and deleted system/bin/factory file!
It will do the trick, it won't boot into factory no more.

Also i've found the files factory_init.project.rc and factory_init.rc in the boot.img.
Now trying to just comment some things out.. and maybe find an even better solution!